# Returning date in US format

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I' like to return this short date in the US format, the current culture of my application is `en-GB`, but I'd like it in `en-US`.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.ToString()` extension method and enter the format:

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

Custom date format options are documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: How is this specific to the en-US culture the OP wants?

Comment: @ken2k Because this is in the `en-US` format (month/day/year). Why do you consider this wrong?

Comment: You sure about that? On my machine it's M/d/yyyy.

Comment: @ken2k actually, we don't know if the OP means "en-US" as understood by .NET or "en-US" as an identifier used in lots of systems for English-language-as-used-in-the-US locale information, so Curt could be closer to what they really want (hence my giving both approaches).

Comment: @ken2k So you're saying `M/d/yyyy` is en-US format but `MM/dd/yyyy` isn't? These are both `month/day/year` formats, its just `MM/dd/yyyy` will display month and date as 2 digits.

Comment: @Curt Yes, so basically those are different patterns. The en-US (as per .Net definition) format has only one digit.

Comment: @ken2k I've seen both formats documentated on msdn, but for arguments sake I've changed the format

Comment: Yes, but now if they change their locale data again, it's wrong in the other direction. Why not just ask .NET what that format is?

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that you are using the right culture format string for this to happen.

One way to get this format directly from the culture is:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

For me this returns `M/d/yyyy`.

```
var usShortDatePattern = 
             CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).ToString(usShortDatePattern);
```

The benefit of doing this is that if a user has overridden the Short Date Pattern for `en-US` in their control panel (Region and Language), they will get the formatting they want.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx):

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to change the current thread culture in order to call a ToXXString() methods. There are DateTime method overloads that take a IFormatProvider as parameter (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12003141/870604)

Comment: @ken2k: That's one way to do it and is documented in the MSDN. I agree, I would rather use your method, now that I know of it :-) Still, **it is not wrong and does not deserve a downvote!**

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't downvoted your answer as it's of course not wrong :)

Comment: @ken2k: I didn't think so, this sentence was meant for the anonymous downvoter. BTW: I found something even shorter, have a look :-)

Comment: The documentation is to explain how `ToShortDateString()` works, for which it needs to change the current locale. It's not appropriate for real code as it could cause a mysterious bug to appear elsewhere in the same application (all of a sudden code in a completely different place that was correctly handling "12,56" for users where that is appropriate as a representation of 12.56 starts throwing exceptions)

Comment: @JonHanna: (1) I removed that part from my answer alltogether already (2) What you say is not true, as the code was setting the current culture *of the current thread*  right before the call to `ToShortDateString` and setting it back to the original culture right afterwards. It is impossible to have effect on any other code. It can't affect threads running in parallel as I am changing the culture only for `CurrentThread`. It can't affect following code in the same thread as I set the culture back after my code finishes. Your downvote is not valid, so please remove it.

Comment: You're assuming that everything always goes perfectly with the code. That's a brittle assumption. You're also assuming I downvoted you, that's a plain-wrong assumption.

Comment: @JonHanna: You could always put the part that sets the culture back in a finally block if that's what concerns you...

Comment: You could. It'd still be strange for a one-off format specification but it wouldn't be as brittle.
I do think your first form - but without the switch back - is worth leaving in as "if what you really want is to be using "en-US" in the first place...", as is "if you really want a custom culture with en-US date formats...", since they're likely scenarios where someone might be thinking "how do I get it American-style?" in the first place (whether the OP or someone else hitting this question).

Answer (score 1):

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
string formatedDate = DateTime
    .Now
    .AddYears(-2)
    .ToString(culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, culture);
```

Answer (score 1):

"I want to apply the en-US short-date-pattern":

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).ToString("d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

"I want to apply the pattern M/d/yyyy regardless of whether .NET thinks that's the short-pattern for en-US or not:

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).ToString(@"M\/d\/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

(Same result as above, but if what you are thinking of as "the US format" was actually MM/dd/yyyy, which is also used in the US, then that's the approach you want, but with `@"MM\/dd\/yyyy"`instead of `@"M\/d\/yyyy"`.

Finally, "I want to find out the en-US short-date-pattern for use with another call:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```